# Unable to ping or RDP to servers via remote access VPN after DNS server change Cisco ASA

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

We have a setup here were users can remote into our network via VPN and then remote to their desktops.

This was all working fine.

The other day, we moved DNS from one server to another.  I changed all the entries I could find in the ASA to the new DNS server's IP but now after connecting via VPN, you can't ping or RDP to any of our servers or desktops via IP or FQDN.

I tried clearing the DNS cache to no avail.

Any ideas as to what I am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the ASA's status and logs? Does the VPN tunnel come up at all? What were the entries you changed?

Comment: Wherever the ASA was referencing the old DC and IP I changed it to the new DC and IP.  DNS entries, etc.

Comment: I was actually asking where that was, specifically. Normally an ASA wouldn't have any dealings with a DC, and should arguably be configured to function even when one DNS server is unavailable, so I'm wondering how you set up your ASA to depend so heavily on that one specific DNS server.

Comment: `but now after connecting via VPN, you can't ping or RDP to any of our servers or desktops via IP or FQDN` - If you can't connect via ip address then the problem is very likely unrelated to DNS.